# Sails pubsub how to subscribe to a model instance?

Tags: sails.js, publish-subscribe

I am struggling to receive pubsub events in my client. The client store (reflux) gets the data from a project using its id. As I understand it this automatically subscribes the Sails socket for realtime events (from version 0.10), but I don't see it happening.

Here's my client store getting data from sails 
*(this is ES6 syntax)*

```
onLoadProject(id) {

 var url = '/api/projects/' + id;

 io.socket.get(url, (p, jwres) => {
   console.log('loaded project', id);
   this.project = p;
   this.trigger(p);
 });

 io.socket.on("project", function(event){
   console.log('realtime event', event);
 });
},
```

Then I created a test "touch" action in my project controller, just to have the modifiedAt field updated.

```
touch: function(req, res){
   var id = req.param('id');

   Project.findOne(id)
  .then(function(project) {
    if (!project) throw new Error('No project with id ' + id);

    return Project.update({id: id}, {touched: project.touched+1});
  })
  .then(function(){
    // this should not be required right?
    return Project.publishUpdate(id);
  })
  .done(function() {
    sails.log('touched ok');
    res.ok();

  }, function(e) {
    sails.log("touch failed", e.message, e.stack);
    res.serverError(e.message);
  });
}
```

This doesn't trigger any realtime event in my client code. I also added a manual Project.publishUpdate(), but this shouldn't be required right?

What am I missing?

-------- edit ----------

There was a complication a result of my model touched attribute, since I set it to 'number' instead of 'integer' and the ORM exception wasn't caught by the promise error handling without a catch() part. So the code above works, hurray! But the realtime events are received for every instance of Project.

So let me rephrase my question:

How can I subscribe the client socket to an instance instead of a model? I could check the id on the client side and retrieve the updated instance data but that seems inefficient since every client receives a notification about every project even though they only should care about a single one.

----- edit again ------

So nevermind. The reason I was getting updates from every instance is simply because at the start of my application I triggered a findAll to get a list of available projects. As a result my socket got subscribed for all of them. The workaround would be to either initiate that call via plain http instead of a socket, or use a separate controller action for retrieving the list (therefor bypassing the blueprint route). I picked the second option because in my case it's silly to fetch all project data prior to picking one.

Comment: I can't say for sure what's up with your code without testing it, but you definitely *do* need the `Project.publishUpdate` in there.  Sails will only automatically send out notifications if you use the [blueprint methods](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Update.html).

Comment: Hm, Works For Me™.  Are you seeing the `loaded project` message?

Comment: Thanks @sgress454, the code works indeed. I have changed the question.

Comment: Hm, no--requesting `/api/projects/123` will only subscribe you to messages about project #123.  You won't receive messages triggered by `Project.publishUpdate(456);`.  I verified this again myself using your code.  If you're seeing messages regardless of which project you "touch", I'd check that the `id` in your first code block is actually defined, and you're not somehow just getting *all* projects (which *would* subscribe you to all messages about projects, including ones you create later).

Comment: Damn sorry about that. I just now realized I'm doing a find all request before loading a specific project to build the list of all available projects. Doh! This would be the reason why my client is subscribed to everything. I will make a separate action for this to avoid that.

Comment: Ok--I would go ahead and post your final observation as an answer, and accept it yourself.  It might help others who come here with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my own question. The reason I was getting updates from every instance is simply because at the start of my application I triggered a findAll to get a list of available projects. As a result my socket got subscribed for all of them.

The workaround would be to either initiate that call via plain http instead of a socket, or use a separate controller action for retrieving the list (therefor bypassing the blueprint route). I picked the second option because in my case it's silly to fetch all resources data prior to selecting one.

Here's the function I used to list all resources, where I filter part of the data which is not relevant for browsing the list initially.

```
list: function(req, res) {

Project.find()
  .then(function(projects) {

    var keys = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'createdAt',
      'updatedAt',
      'author',
      'description',
    ];

    return projects.map(function(project){
      return _.pick(project, keys);
    });
  })
  .catch(function (e){
    res.serverError(e.message);
  })
  .done(function(list){
    res.json(list);
  }, function(e) {
    res.serverError(e.message);
  });
```

},

Note that when the user loads a resource (project in my case) and then switches to another resource, the client is will be subscribed to both resources. I believe it requires a request to an action where you unsubscribe the socket explicitly to prevent this. In my case this isn't such a problem, but I plan to solve that later.

I hope this is helpful to someone.